# xcode 14 Storyboard clicking UIViewController's name but not navigate to its class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode14

[image: storyboard custom class screenshot]

I recently updated my xcode to 14.2, after that i'm no longer able to go to view controller's class from storyboard by clicking to the right arrow which is on the right of class name.

Note: I unchecked SystemPreferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts->AppShortcuts->Show Help menu and on the xcode preferences set comment out to cmd+shift+7. Not sure if it is related but i wanted you to know.

Comment: Same issue,  any solution?